# What can be done to diagnose node server suddenly failing to respond to requests

Tags: node.js

I am using pm2 to run node in production, and the server will suddenly stop responding to requests after a couple of hours.  Pm2 says the process is still online and everything is good.  The logs don't say anything relevant.  There seems to be free memory:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3840472     653388    3187084          0      65356     332088
-/+ buffers/cache:     255944    3584528
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Is there any ideas as to of what I could do to diagnose the issue?

PM2 Config:

```
[{
  "name"             : "app",
  "cwd"              : "/var/www/app",
  "script"           : "app.js",
  "error_file"       : "/var/log/app/platform.stderr.log",
  "out_file"         : "/var/log/app/platform.stdout.log",
  "run_as_user"      : "ubuntu",
  "instances"        : "max",
  "cron_restart"     : "1 0 * * *",
  "watch"            : "false",
  "ignoreWatch"      : ["[\\/\\\\]\\./", "node_modules"],
  "merge_logs"       : "true",
  "exec_interpreter" : "node",
  "exec_mode"        : "fork",
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "production",
    "PORT": "80"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Can you confirm that node receives the requests? Do requests timeout?

Comment: Here is the URL: http://54.164.175.216/
Failed
Remote server closed the connection before sending response header

Comment: I believe this is PM2 related, because another node application that I recently switched to PM2 is now doing the same behavior...  I will post my PM2 config.